# regexp replace in hive

Tags: json, hive, regexp-replace

I have the following string:

```
{module={"mine":"name"}, objDetails=[{"type":"name","objId":"6666666666",
"objsource":{"sourceId":{"id":"8888888"},"sourceType":"XML","name":"4444.XML"}}],
stl={"sl":"lag1","t1":["lag2"]}, dateinMillis=3864235432, name="[sample1] [sample2] 
str: strngggg 8: \"some random string\" [lan1 > lan2]", description="string1: string 9: \"few more string\" [s1 > s2]", booleanflag=false, state="whatever", 
imp="no", id="723542345"}
```

I want to convert this to a proper JSON string in Hive.

Comment: The provided information is not enough to figure out what you trying to achieve. why are you trying regexp replace?

Comment: i am trying to convert this into a valid json so i can process the data.basically i want to pull out the values for description,name using a json function in hive(get_json_object(data_json,'$.decription') should return the proper string